# How to use streaming replication and logical replication together in Postgresql 12

Tags: postgresql

I have PG 12 on my production server with streaming replication for HA. I want to upgrade PG 12 to PG 13 and want to minimize downtime in few minutes instead of hours.

Can we use logical replication with streaming replication together? I see that we can not set wal_level = replica, logical.

I have DB size 125 GB so it takes  time while upgrading using pg_upgrade or dump/ restore approach.
Any hint or other way to do same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`replica` < `logical`, so setting `wal_level` to the latter will allow both streaming replication and logical replication. There is no problem in using both at the same time.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz,                                           
Yes I just read it in Postgresql document. In logical level, the same information is logged as with replica, plus information needed to allow extracting logical change sets from the WAL. Using a level of logical will increase the WAL volume, particularly if many tables are configured for REPLICA IDENTITY FULL and many UPDATE and DELETE statements are executed.

Comment: @DarshanShah Did you find the way to upgrade the existing cluster(two/three node) which were using streaming replication? Can you please list the steps which you used.

Comment: Hi Niraj,                                                                                                                         
       Logical replication will not work for me as there are some limitations. So I will use pg_upgrade or side by side upgradation by creating new VM and restore backup with down time.